# Proper Detection whether UNC volume online

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

What is the proper method to determine whether a UNC volume is online if you only have the share root \VOLUME\SHARE

My old solution (written 10 years ago) was to read the drive root.  If I found something then I assumed all was well.  But with UNC permissions aren't always there for access to that.

What API is the proper way to determine whether a UNC volume is online for offline?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious approach would be to use [NetShareCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525385.aspx).

Comment: I didn't find this function to be reliable